# Text/Icons Missing after Unlocking Screen

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, gnome, display, desktop-environments

On Ubuntu 20.04, I sometimes notice that after unlocking screen, text is missing from dialog boxes:

[image]

[image]

and icons missing from the task bar (left hand side, orange dots visible):

[image]

The clock and mini icons at the top of the screen are missing too.

Is there a way to get them back without restarting the system? I have numerous applications running and want to avoid having to save and restart them.

```
$ nvidia-smi
Sun Nov  7 14:03:07 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.91.03    Driver Version: 460.91.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 207...  Off  | 00000000:2D:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 86%   85C    P2   147W / 235W |   6939MiB /  7979MiB |     99%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 207...  Off  | 00000000:2E:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 82%   81C    P2   181W / 235W |   4932MiB /  7982MiB |    100%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

```
$ ls /usr/bin/*session
/usr/bin/dbus-run-session  /usr/bin/gnome-session  /usr/bin/gnome-session-custom-session
```

```
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.9
```